# Python MySQL decorator retrieving rows but returning None

Tags: python, mysql

I'm writing a decorator to shorten my code (And because this is the first time I get to use decorators). In the select function, when print(rows) runs, I see list of carriers I inserted into my DB, but when I print(carriers), it returns None.

What's going on?

```
def mysql_wrapper(function):
    def wrapper(query, data=None):
        conn = db_connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        if data:
            cursor.execute(query,data)
        else:
            cursor.execute(query)
        function(cursor)
        cursor.close()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    return wrapper

@mysql_wrapper
def query(cursor):
    pass

@mysql_wrapper
def select(cursor):
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    return rows

carriers = select('SELECT * FROM carriers')
print(carriers)
```

Comment: Do you already tried see the `contextlib` ?
https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/contextlib.html

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add a return statement in the wrapper function.

```
return rows
```

returns the rows to the wrapper function, where they sit idly, so I edited the function slightly and now everything works.

```
def mysql_wrapper(function):
    def wrapper(query, data=None):
        conn = db_connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        if data:
            cursor.execute(query,data)
        else:
            cursor.execute(query)
        rows = function(cursor)        #Here
        cursor.close()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return rows                    #Here
    return wrapper
```

I've been reading too many 'Decorator' guides and started skimming through the examples instead of actually reading them. I simply missed that detail.

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question, put it in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I rolled it back because the solution doesn't belong in the question.